# Vaadin Flow renderer for java.time date-time types beyond just LocalDateTime & LocalDate classes

Tags: java, vaadin, java-time, vaadin-flow, dateformatter

In Vaadin Flow version 14.1, I find only two implementations of a renderer for date-time types:

- [`LocalDateRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/data/renderer/LocalDateRenderer.html)
- [`LocalDateTimeRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/data/renderer/LocalDateTimeRenderer.html)

The first is for a date-only value in the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class, without a time-of-day and without a time zone. That is good.

The second is for [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class representing a date with time-of-day, but purposely lacking the context of a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or a [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). Well enough.

The problem is that I can find no other renderers for the several other *java.time* data types. Here is a chart I made of the various date-time types, the modern *java.time* types, as well as the legacy date-time classes they supplant, and a list of the SQL-standard equivalent data-types.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

Specifically, in business app we tend to use `LocalDateTime` less frequently, mainly for booking future appointments when the definition of a time zone can be changed by politicians (which they have been shown to do quite frequently, around the world). That `LocalDateTime` class cannot represent a moment. For example, take January 23rd this year at 3 PM. Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, we do not know if this means 3 PM in Tokyo Japan, 3 PM in Toulouse France, or 3 PM in Toledo Ohio US — three very different moments several hours apart.

To represent a moment, we must use the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) classes. An `Instant` is a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), always in UTC by definition. A `OffsetDateTime` represents a moment with an offset-from-UTC of some number of hours-minutes-seconds. A `ZonedDateTime` is a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, a time zone. Such a time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used in that region.

➥ Does Vaadin 14 provide renderers for any of these other types? If not, is there  a workaround, or a way to make a renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## My `InstantRenderer` class

You can easily create your own implementation of a renderer.

Here is the renderer I wrote to handle a `Grid` widget displaying objects that include an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object. An `Instant` is a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). The `Instant` class is the basic building block class used in the *java.time* framework.

The idea here is that we take the `Instant` object, apply a specified [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. That `ZonedDateTime` object uses the specified [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object to generate text in a `String` object. The text represents the contents of the `ZonedDateTime` object [automatically localized](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) to the specified [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) object's human language and cultural norms.

[image: diagram showing how the <code>DateTimeFormatter</code> object provides a <code>ZoneId</code> object used by the <code>InstantRenderer</code> to produce a <code>ZonedDateTime</code> which in turn uses the <code>DateTimeFormatter</code> to generate automatically localized text for presentation to the user]

The `ZoneId` and the `Locale` are attached to the `DateTimeFormatter` passed by the calling programmer.

My code here is based on the code published by the Vaadin Ltd company for their [`LocalDateTimeRenderer`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/data/renderer/LocalDateTimeRenderer.html) class’ [source-code found on their GitHub site](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/master/flow-data/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/data/renderer/LocalDateTimeRenderer.java).

I pruned the API of that class. Their API allowed for passing a formatting-pattern string rather than a `DateTimeFormatter` object. I do not believe it should be the responsibility of the renderer to produce a formatter object from such a string, and therefore too handle any resulting error conditions. And their API allowed for passing a `Locale` object. The `Locale` object can be attached to the `DateTimeFormatter` object being passed by the calling programmer. I do not see how this renderer class should be getting needlessly involved in assigning the passed locale to the passed formatter. The calling programming can do that assignment *before* passing the formatter to our renderer.

Here is typical usage in defining a `InstantRenderer` for rendering a `Instant` object for display within a `Grid` in Vaadin 14.

```
invoicesGrid
        .addColumn(
                new InstantRenderer <>( Invoice :: getWhenCreated ,
                        DateTimeFormatter
                                .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT , FormatStyle.MEDIUM )
                                .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )
                                .withZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
                )
        )
        .setHeader( "Created" )
;
```

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Be aware that the *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). The [`withZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone(java.time.ZoneId)) and [`withLocale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale(java.util.Locale)) methods produce a new fresh `DateTimeFormatter` rather than altering the original. So you might want to keep a global singleton `DateTimeFormatter` with your preference for short date and longer time-of-day.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter
                                .ofLocalizedDateTime( 
                                    FormatStyle.SHORT ,   // Length of date portion.
                                    FormatStyle.MEDIUM    // Length of time-of-day portion.
                                )
;
```

Then elsewhere in your code, apply each user’s own preferred zone and locale. You get another, specialized, `DateTimeFormatter` object while the original remains unaffected due to the immutable objects pattern used in *java.time*.

```
invoicesGrid
        .addColumn(
                new InstantRenderer <>( Invoice :: getWhenCreated ,
                        f
                                .withLocale( user.getPreferredLocale()  )
                                .withZone( user.getPreferredZone() )
                )
        )
        .setHeader( "Created" )
;
```

By the way, there is a third optional argument to the constructors: a `String` to be used in case the `Instant` object being rendered is null. The default is to present no text at all to the user, an empty `""` string. You may pass some other string if you wish, such as `null` or `void`.

And here is the source-code of my class. Notice that I put some discussion in the Javadoc near the top.

I am using the same Apache License 2 as does Vaadin Ltd, so you may use and change this code for yourself. Your feedback is welcome.

```
package work.basil.example.ui;

/*
 * Copyright 2000-2020 Vaadin Ltd.
 * Copyright 2020 Basil Bourque.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */


import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

import com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.BasicRenderer;
import com.vaadin.flow.function.ValueProvider;

/*
 * This class is based on source-code directly copied from
 * `LocalDateTimeRenderer.java` of Vaadin 14.1.x
 * as written and published by Vaadin Ltd. from their GitHub page.
 *
 * https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/master/flow-data/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/data/renderer/LocalDateTimeRenderer.java
 *
 * I re-purposed that class to handle `Instant` objects rather than `LocalDateTime`
 * objects. An `Instant` represents a moment, whereas `LocalDateTime` cannot because
 * of it lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. In contrast, `Instant`
 * represents a moment in UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds).
 *
 * By default, a `Instant` object renders in Vaadin by way of its `toString` method
 * generating text in standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSSSZ.
 *
 * If you want other than ISO 8601 format in UTC, use this class. In this class, we
 * apply  a time zone (`ZoneId`) to the `Instant` to adjust from UTC.
 *
 * The `ZoneId` object comes from one of three places:
 *  - Passed implicitly by being set as a property on a `DateTimeFormatter`
 *    object passed as an argument. This is the best case.
 *  - Defaults to calling `ZoneId.systemDefault` if  not found
 *    on the `DateTimeFormatter` object  (where `getZone` returns null).
 *
 * I deleted the constructors taking a formatting pattern string. Parsing such a string
 * and instantiating a `DateTimeFormatter` and handling resulting error conditions
 * should *not* be the job of this class. I believe the Vaadin team made a poor choice
 * in having constructors taking a string formatting pattern rather than just a
 * `DateTimeFormatter` object.
 *
 * Locale is another critical issue. A `Locale` object determines:
 *
 * (a) The human language used for translating items such as name of month and
 * name of day.
 *
 * (b) The cultural norms used in deciding localization issues such as the ordering
 * of elements (ex: day comes before or after month), abbreviation, capitalization,
 * punctuation, and so on.
 *
 * Again, I deleted the constructors taking a `Locale` object. The `DateTimeFormatter`
 * object passed by the calling programmer carries a `Locale`. That calling programmer
 * should have attached their intended locale object to that `DateTimeFormatter` object
 * by calling `DateTimeFormatter::withLocale`. Usually a `DateTimeFormatter` has a default
 * `Locale` assigned. But if found lacking, here we attach the JVM’s current default locale.
 *
 * Following the logic discussed above, I chose to not take a `ZoneId` as an argument.
 * A `ZoneId` can be attached to the `DateTimeFormatter` by calling `withZoneId`.
 * If the passed `DateTimeFormatter` is found lacking, here we attach the JVM’s current
 * default time zone.
 *
 * Typical usage, passing 2 arguments, a method reference and a `DateTimeFormatter` object
 * while omitting 3rd optional argument for null-representation to go with an blank empty string:
 *
 *     myGrid
 *          .addColumn(
 *                  new InstantRenderer <>( TheBusinessObject :: getWhenCreated ,
 *                          DateTimeFormatter
 *                                  .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT , FormatStyle.MEDIUM )
 *                                  .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )
 *                                  .withZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
 *                  )
 *         )
 *
 * This code is written for Java 8 or later.
 *
 *  For criticisms and suggestions, contact me via LinkedIn at:  basilbourque
 */

/**
 * A template renderer for presenting {@code Instant} objects.
 *
 * @param <SOURCE> the type of the input item, from which the {@link Instant}
 *                 is extracted
 * @author Vaadin Ltd
 * @since 1.0.
 */
public class InstantRenderer < SOURCE >
        extends BasicRenderer < SOURCE, Instant >
{
    private DateTimeFormatter formatter;
    private String nullRepresentation;

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the format style
     * {@code FormatStyle.LONG} for the date and {@code FormatStyle.SHORT} for
     * time, with an empty string as its null representation.
     *
     * @param valueProvider the callback to provide a {@link Instant} to the
     *                      renderer, not <code>null</code>
     * @see <a href=
     * "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#LONG">
     * FormatStyle.LONG</a>
     * @see <a href=
     * "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#SHORT">
     * FormatStyle.SHORT</a>
     */
    public InstantRenderer (
            ValueProvider < SOURCE, Instant > valueProvider )
    {
        this(
                valueProvider ,
                DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG )
                        .withZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() )
                        .withLocale( Locale.getDefault() ) ,
                ""
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the given formatter, with the
     * empty string as its null representation.
     *
     * @param valueProvider the callback to provide a {@link Instant} to the
     *                      renderer, not <code>null</code>
     * @param formatter     the formatter to use, not <code>null</code>
     */
    public InstantRenderer (
            ValueProvider < SOURCE, Instant > valueProvider ,
            DateTimeFormatter formatter
    )
    {
        this(
                valueProvider ,
                formatter ,
                ""
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the given formatter.
     *
     * @param valueProvider      the callback to provide a {@link Instant} to the
     *                           renderer, not <code>null</code>
     * @param formatter          the formatter to use, not <code>null</code>
     * @param nullRepresentation the textual representation of the <code>null</code> value
     */
    public InstantRenderer (
            final ValueProvider < SOURCE, Instant > valueProvider ,
            final DateTimeFormatter formatter ,
            final String nullRepresentation
    )
    {
        super( valueProvider );

        this.formatter = Objects.requireNonNull( formatter , "formatter may not be null" );
        this.nullRepresentation = Objects.requireNonNull( nullRepresentation , "null-representation may not be null" );

        // If the formatter provided by the calling programmer lacks a time zone, apply the JVM's current default zone.
        // This condition is less than ideal. The calling programmer should have set an appropriate zone.
        // Often the appropriate zone is one specifically chosen or confirmed by the user.
        if ( Objects.isNull( this.formatter.getZone() ) )
        {
            this.formatter = this.formatter.withZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() );
        }

        // If the formatter provided by the calling programmer lacks a locale, apply the JVM's current default locale.
        // This condition is less than ideal. The calling programmer should have set an appropriate locale.
        // Often the appropriate locale is one specifically chosen or confirmed by the user.
        if ( Objects.isNull( this.formatter.getLocale() ) )
        {
            this.formatter = this.formatter.withLocale( Locale.getDefault() );
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected String getFormattedValue ( final Instant instant )
    {
        // If null, return the null representation.
        // If not null, adjust the `Instant` from UTC into the time zone attached to the `DateTimeFormatter` object.
        // This adjustment, made by calling `Instant::atZone`, produces a `ZonedDateTime` object.
        // We then create a `String` with text representing the value of that `ZonedDateTime` object.
        // That text is automatically localized per the `Locale` attached to the `DateTimeFormatter` object.
        String s = Objects.isNull( instant ) ? nullRepresentation : formatter.format( instant.atZone( this.formatter.getZone() ) );
        return s;
    }
}
```

Perhaps I can later do something similar for the other *java.time* types seen listed in the Question.